# How to read a txt file with characters (without spacing) and store into a 2D character array with 15x15 in visual c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm kind of a newbie in C++ programming.. My command prompt output is a big bulk (repeated) of the characters I have in my txt file. I create a 2d array map[15][15] and try to read the txt file. the reading part is ok but now I dunno how to put them in a 2D character array..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char map[15][15];
int alp = 0;
int i = 0;
int main()
{
  ifstream in;
  //string s;

  in.open("city.txt");
  if(!in.is_open())
  {
    cout << "File open error! " << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    while(!in.eof())
    {
      //getline(in, s);
      in >> map[i];
      i++;
      alp++;
      //if(in.eof()) break;
      cout << map[i] << endl;
    }
  }
  for(i = 0; i <= alp; i++)
  {
    cout << map[i];
  }

  in.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(!in.eof())` [No!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/560648) What learning resource has taught you to do that? I need to know so that I may begin disrecommending it.

Comment: How is the data stored in the file? Is the data stored per line or per column? Are there spaces or newlines separating data? Maybe you can edit your question to include an example file?

Comment: my lecturer taught me.. it's to perform the task while it's not end of file, is that wrong? I was told this is in case the user pressed Enter after the last data in the txt file..I used getline(in,s) and if(in.eof()) break; in 1st step to display the characters.. then while referring to other questions I added the for() part..

Comment: I need to store in a 2D array that has 15 elements with 15 (rows or data) in each element.. there's no separating data, cuz I need to create a map like this:
xxxrxxxrxxrxrxx
rrrrxrrrxrrrrrr
xxxrxxxrxxrxrxx
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrx
xxxrxcxcxxxrxrr
xxrrccxcxccrrrx
xxrxxcxcxcxrxrx
rrrrxcccccxrxrx
xxrxxcxxxcxrxrx
rrrrccxccccrrrr
xxxrxcxcxcxrxrx
rrxrxrrrrrxrxrr
xrxrxrxrxrxrxrx
rrrrrrxrxrrrrrr
xxrxxrxrxrxxxxx

Comment: There's nothing separating even the rows? So in the file it's like `xxxrxxxrxxrxrxxrrrrxrrrxrrrrrrxxxrxxxrxxrxrxxrrrrrrrrrrrrrrx...` etc.?

Comment: there is. every 15 characters then enter nxt line and 15 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

eof() will only return true only **after** the first failed read operation. That operation will not be caught by your code. You could have a test for eof directly after the read and then break if eof(), but that's not elegant:

IO operations on streams return a ref to the given stream. Streams have a meaningful conversion to bool. True indicates that the read was successful, e.g. eof wasn't reached yet, and the read target contains a new correct input value. The idiomatic way of using this feature is "while(in >>  map[i])".

As to the algorithm: You say that there are no spaces and I assume it's all ascii chars, so it boils down to double looping over the array's lines and columns with two for loops. Inside those loops would be a line reading each character explicitly with get() like

```
if(!cin.get(map[i][j])) {/* unexpected eof/io error, abort or whatever */ }
```

Comment: Do nothing in the loop body, except perhaps increase the index variables?

Comment: This is a statement nested in two for loops which I mentioned in the text but didn't code out. Maybe misunderstandable...

Comment: @Joachim Right, that was a superfluous while loop... One could actually C like use a simple char* and just increment it for 15*15 times in a single loop, would be less wordy.

Comment: If we can rely on the right file size we can write "for( char *p = (char *)map; in.get(*p); ++p);" .

Comment: Guys I have the solution given by my lecturer:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 ifstream in;
 char s;
 char map[15][15];
 int i,j, r = 0, c = 0;

 in.open("city.txt");
 if(!in.is_open())
  {
   cout << "File open error! " << endl;
  }
 else
  {
   while(!in.eof())
   {
    in >> s;
    if(in.eof()) break;
    map[r][c] = s;
    c++;
    if(c > 14)
    {
     r++;
     c = 0;
    }
   }
   in.close();

   for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
   {
    for(j = 0; j < 15; j++)
     cout << map[i][j];
    cout << endl;
   }
  }
 
 return 0;
}
Thx guys!

Comment: What I like about it is (1) using operator>>(char&) deals with arbitrary file formats (with/without line breaks, spaces etc.) (2) the code contains "c++" ;-). What I find doubtful is (1) the redundant while(eof) because, correctly, the code checks for eof after each lines and breaks the loop anyway, so the while can never be true (even not with an empty file, before the first read attempt). (2) And then, a 2-dimensional array just calls for a nested index loop, or is that just me? Emulating the loop by resetting the indices after (if > 14) seems too low-level. Can I post this at code review?

Answer (score 0):

As the data is textual, and separated into lines, I suggest you read directly into the sub-array using e.g. [`std:istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline):

```
for (size_t i = 0; in.getline(map[i], 15); ++i)
    ;
```